# How to tell a theme to use different .mo and .po files?

Tags: themes, multi-language, translation

I have a theme which loads .po and .mo files to display strings in English. I want to have only one language (Polish), but those two files are en_US. I tried replacing content in the en_US.po file but nothing changed on the website, I do not know why. Where does it store strings if changing .po files changes nothing?

Comment: Take a look at [Translating Wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Translating_WordPress) to get to know what you're dealing with. Besides that, you probably haven't generated the corresponding mo-file. Additionally you really shouldn't use the english translation file for the polish translation.

Comment: To further your reading, I did an answer a while ago. Go check it out http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/137727/31545

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are already an `en_US.po` file in the theme you are using. You can simply make a copy of that file and rename it as `pl_PL.po`. You can now open the `pl_PL.po` template with [poedit](http://www.poedit.net/), do all your translations in there, and just save it. Poedit will automatically create a `pl_PL.mo` template.

No need to go through all the pt. Just remember, as previously stated, change the language in the `wp-config.php` to `pl_PL`

Comment: My pleasure. Glad I could be of help

Comment: yeeah we try to make good answers that's why I wrote all the steps...

Answer (score 3):

Hi to translate your website you can do the following:

1. Define your language in `wp-config.php` : `define('WPLANG', 'pl_PL');`
2. Then generate a po file for your theme with e.g this service: [iCanLocalize Scanner](https://www.icanlocalize.com/tools/php_scanner)
3. Then your po and mo files should be named `pl_PL.po` and `pl_PL.mo` and put into a folder called languages or lang or something like this in your theme.
4. **if not**, create a folder for languages and then use [load_theme_textdomain](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/load_theme_textdomain) (or `load_child_theme_textdomain` if it's a child theme)
5. If there's already a language folder with po and mo files just put your new files in the same folder.

With this you should be able to easily translate your site.

**EDIT:** if there's a pot file in your theme folder use it directly to generate po and mo files.

Comment: Just in case if you are looking for the "languages" directory for the theme, it works for me when I put the corresponding language .po and .mo into where default.po and default.mo are located.

Answer (score 0):

Go to ADMIN Dashboard and than go to Settings -> General and select your language (Polish).

You can define by yourself the language via the wp-config.php file in you wordpress root directory:
define('WPLANG', 'pl_PL');

Comment: No need to install a plugin for a basic function of Wordpress.

Comment: Yeah, this post is from 4 years ago....I edit right now the answer for the best practice. the recommendation for using plugin is to translate the strings if needed