# How to extract translatable (double underscores and _e) strings?

Tags: translation

I made a custom theme and wonder how could I extract all translatable strings to a .po file so I can translate it. Do I need WPML plugin?

Ex: I have a string "soccer" which is written as `_e('soccer','mytheme');` and I want to translate it to "futebol" but how can I transport it to a .po file?

Comment: Check this [post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/137727/31545)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use the WordPress i18n tools. I had to checkout WordPress trunk to make it work. On the command line:

```
svn co http://develop.svn.wordpress.org/trunk
```

once you have trunk somewhere, you'll then want to call the `makepot` script. Again, on the command line:

```
php /path/to/wordpress/trunk/tools/i18n/makepot.php wp-theme /path/to/your/theme/
```

After that script has run, the pot files will be in whatever directory was specified in the above `/path/to/your/theme`

More information and a couple of other methods can be seen here: http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers

Answer (score 1):

You can extract traslatable (gettext) strings from a Wordpress Theme or Plugin with [wp-cli](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/i18n/make-pot/). To install:

- Visit [oficial documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/i18n/make-pot/).
- Use Homebrew (mac): `brew install wp-cli`

Once you have it, you run the following command:

`wp i18n . path/to/domain_name.pot --domain=domain_name`

(Run from the theme/plugin root folder, where `domain_name` is the domain you've used on the code.)

This will generate a `.pot` file. You can use software like POEdit to open the `.pot` file and do the translations. This software will then let you export to `.po` and `.mo`.

You can find more info on [I18n for Wordpress Developers](https://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers).