# Understanding Wordpress Default Theme - twentyfifteen.1.4 >> Languages Folder

Tags: translation, theme-twenty-fourteen

**Understanding Wordpress Default Theme - Twentyfifteen.1.4** is the standardized theme designed by the wordpress people. in the language folder there is a template. just like we have .php extension or .js or .css No extension is showed there. it Just says Type: **Translation Type**.

Please see this snapshot - http://screencast.com/t/s08NswYAzmJ4
can some one please help me to understand what extension type is this and how can one create this?

Alternatively you can also download twentyfifteen.1.4 theme from [here](https://downloads.wordpress.org/theme/twentyfifteen.1.4.zip).

Comment: It is a `.pot` file. This is the "master" translation file which holds all the translatable strings. Using a program like *poedit*, you can create your own `.po` and ultimately `.mo` file which will hold your localized strings

Comment: And preparing this file is an automated process or this has to be done mannualy?

Comment: You should read  [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/137727/31545)